# Problems setting up Davmail in Kubuntu 11.04

Tags: kubuntu, ms-exchange

Haven't had a chance to setup Davmail per the earlier discussion around connecting to my Exchange box w/ Kontact but tonight I had some free time.

So  I have Davmail installed and working I thinking, but the problem that I am running into is the icon doesn't not show up in the system tray.  The documentation says right-click o the tray, but there are no icons to right click on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Running Kubuntu 11.04

Thanks,

Jonathn

Answer (score 3):

http://sourceforge.net/users/raducotescu/

This is not a bug. It's a new feature in Ubuntu 11.04 where the systray is only used by indicators and not regular applications. To overcome this, you can enter the following command in a terminal and then restart your sessions (log out and log back in):

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```